# PHP: make a folder's files accessible, only after a successful login

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

Right now, in my website, i have managed to redirect the user, after successful login, to a `www.mysite.com/protected_files/redirect.php` page by using something like this on my *www.mysite.com/login.php* page:

```
if( login was successful)
{
    include('protected_files/redirect.php');
}
```

The folder named *`www.mysite.com/protected_files`*, contains an `.htaccess` file,

```
 # This file prevents that your .php view files are accessed directly from the outside
 <Files ~ "\.(htaccess|php)$">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 </Files>
```

which is causing all .php files in the `protected_files` folder to give users a 403 error, when they type in their browser `www.mysite.com/protected_files/phpfile1.php`

Which is where the function `include('protected_files/anyphpfile.php')` comes in handy.

Now, i am trying to figure out how to redirect the user from `protected_files/phpfile1.php` to `protected_files/phpfile2.php` from a menu bar.

`<a href="www.mysite.com/protected_files/phpfile2.php">page2</a>` is not working (error 403), because it belongs in the `protected_files` folder, which has the `.htaccess` file, and it makes it not aaccessible from a url.

My solution to this matter, was something like:

```
//code in `www.mysite.com/redirect.php`
if ($_GET['page'] == "phpfile2") {
include("phpfile2.php");
} else {    
include("phpfile1.php");
}
```

Which means that after a successful login, users would be taken to `www.mysite.com/protected_files/phpfile1.php` by default (since `$_GET['page'] == ""`)

Now, the user is in `phpfile1.php` and he can click on an link `<a href="?page=phpfile2">phpfile2</a>` to go to `phpfile2.php`. While doing that, his browser at first shows `www.mysite.com/login.php` and after he clicks on the link , it shows `www.mysite.com/login.php?page=phpfile2`.

What i am trying to do is **not show** `www.mysite.com/login.php?page=phpfile2` in the url , when the user is in the `phpfile2.php` page , **but to show the actual file path**, which is `www.mysite.com/protected_files/phpfile2.php`

**How can i achieve that in this particular case?**

Could i possibly change the `.htaccess` so that `protected_files` becomes reachable (no more error 403) after a successful login ? Should i change the way i made this site completely ?

**Basically, in the end, i want to have a folder, named `protected_files`, which contains .php files that are available to the user, only after a successful login.**

Comment: er... you cannot make htaccess read your PHP login session, but I'm not sure why you'd want to. You know and understand that PHP includes have nothing to do with whether a directory is protected. Maybe I'm reading this wrong since the case appears overly complicated, but why can't you just do a pure htaccess redirect that rewrites the URL? That is NOT, however, a form of security. The correct way to secure this is to quietly include whatever you want based on logins and sessions, and not rely on htaccess. Totally block the scripts folder with htaccess, and php will still include from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 <Files ~ "\.(htaccess|php)$">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 </Files>
```

to

```
 <Files ~ "\.(htaccess|include)$">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 </Files>

 <Files ~ "\.php$">
 php_value auto_prepend_file "session_check.include"
 </Files>
```

Then have `session_check.include` check to see if the user is logged in; if not, call `exit()`. Then every file in the directory will check whether the user is logged in; if they are not, it will exit. If they are, the file will continue like normal.

This way, you don't have to do a bunch of tricks rewriting the inbound and outbound requests to match some faked up map - you just let each file load the "are you logged in yet?" check as the first thing it does.

See [How to change configuration settings](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) for documentation on how the `php_value` works, and [Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) for documentation on `auto_prepend_file`

Comment: hello, intresting answer, in my case i am using http://www.php-login.net/ code ( the minimal version ) , and the way login is check is like this `$login = new Login();`   `if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true)` how would i make your code to work in my case ?

Comment: `$login = new Login(); if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() !== true) { exit(); }` - or you could do something more useful than `exit()`, such as throwing a 403 or redirecting the user to the login form.

Comment: um , where would this code go to ? , right now its on the www.mysite.com/login.php

Comment: In `session_check.include` (or whatever you want to call the file that gets auto_prepended into each and every PHP file in the protected directory).

Comment: this is so wildly contrary to the way I've ever written any code, at first I thought it was completely bonkers; looking at it, I can see it could have some utility. It is still a completely horribly shotgun way of granting or denying access. You should really never have a ton of separate PHP "pages" to begin with, you should be writing classes that fill parts in a framework. The use cases for something like this besides sharing movie files or other kinds of raw data are hard to think of -- and there would be better ways to do that.

Comment: um , i am actually a begginer in php , `session_check.include` doesnt sound like a file name to me , should it end with .php or something ? the actual filename is session_check.php ? and i need to add $login = new Login(); if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() !== true) { exit(); } this code there ? and change my `.htaccess` file as you showed in you answer ?

Comment: You could name it `.php` - I chose `.include` so that it doesn't get executed by the PHP engine (because the code in that file would never have meaning outside of the auto_include context), so we can add it to the <Files> block that just denies any requests for that page through the httpd. The name of the file really isn't important in this case, as it's going to be included whole-sale into each script.

Comment: @joshstrike i dont have a ton of pages, i just have 2 as i said in my question , the content of those pages is something like `admin panel` to give you an idea, so this content shouldnt be shown, unless you login as admin.

Comment: Shiro, if you are new at PHP, do not rely on htaccess. Htaccess is fine to seal off your php files -- PHP include() does not care at all about htaccess. Create a public page that includes the important parts. Just use your login data to decide which files to include and block ALL files behind the htaccess wall. Then you can use a simple htaccess in the public folder to rewrite the URL string -- that is a completely separate issue.

Comment: @TML thanks a lot buddie, you seem pretty skilled in php, very accurate answer in such little time , i ll try your solution tomorrow since i spent 1 hour writing with question, i appreciate your answer , thanks

Comment: @joshstrike if i didnt edit my `.htaccess` my `admin panel` would be accessible just by using its url. how would i make sure that only loged in users (admins) can access the `admin panel` page ?

Comment: As @joshstrike suggests, you'll likely soon find that you wish you had written the whole application in an object oriented manner. I would recommend taking some time to pick apart some of the larger PHP frameworks and see what they've done; there are good lesson in those -- in both the "do this" and the "don't do this" sense of "lessons." :)

Comment: @TML am i right on this last comment i made TML ? isnt this true ? if you dont change your .htaccess , the admin panel would be visible if you had its url , right ?

Comment: The .htaccess solution is one possible method. Another method is to use an object oriented approach where method calls check the rights of the logged-in user to see whether that individual has access to the features implemented in this method.

Comment: how else would i ensure that if you are not logged in , you cant open a specific .php file in your browser

Comment: @joshstrike is suggesting that "can load the file" or "cannot load the file" is a really coarse-grained method of doing permissions; that kind of thing will often grow into a desired for finer-grained permissions where you can say "Group Admin" (has rights to modify things for the groups he's part of) vs. "Site Admin" (can modify everything in his domain) vs. "Super Admin" (can modify everything for everyone in all domains).

Comment: @Shiro imagine if you have an outer folder called "public" and there you have an htaccess that silently redirects /admin to index.php?a=admin and /user to index.php?a=user. Then in your index.php file you check the session and include the correct REAL page -- but the real page is sealed off inside a folder that NO ONE has access to directly. That's the right way to do it, in very basic terms.

Comment: The method you are describing , is exactly what i am doing right now . isnt it ? but i get the awkward url ?a=admin , where as i would much rather have www.something.com/admin . Right now i cant another way of doing this ...

Comment: I do want to say that the more I think about it, @TML your answer is pretty bang on for the actual question, and for certain specific things I can think of ... I fear this isn't one of those things, but I never tried to rewire/append htaccess through php that way, and for file access it could be very useful.

Comment: @Shiro Not quite, no. See [this Wordpress Admin file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: e.g. from that file:    `if ( is_blog_admin() && current_user_can('edit_posts') ) wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'dashboard_right_now', __( 'At a Glance' ), 'wp_dashboard_right_now' ); if ( is_network_admin() ) wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'network_dashboard_right_now', __( 'Right Now' ), 'wp_network_dashboard_right_now' );`

Comment: This is the "a bunch of tricks rewriting the inbound and outbound requests to match some faked up map" I referenced earlier :)

Comment: by the way @TML `php_value auto_prepend_file `  this is how i am supposed to write my .html access file ? are `php_value` and `auto_prepend_file `  keywords ? or you just used those words to explain how its done ?

Comment: Added links in my answer to documentation for both `php_value` and `auto_prepend_file`.

Comment: @TML I got that reference about a faked up map ;) that bunch of tricks is just what happens when applications grow, though. More user states, more levels of access, more checks. They should all be kept in some static class and organized... but... yeah that's life.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bad approach, I would instead keep protected folder outside docroot (so you won't need to use an .htaccess file), and have a gateway script that validates the user is authenticated before redirecting (through a variable stored in the session that indicates this).

Right now, anyone that knows the parameter you expect through GET will be able to figure out the URL where your protected files live and will be able to access them, if you use a gateway script that validates user is authenticated before allowing access to those files, it'll make your files safer.

Answer (score 1):

In your htaccess file -- the one pertaining to the index.php, not the one in the hidden folder which is blocking everything -- you can add something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^admin$ index.php?a=admin [L]
```

and then all links to /admin will be redirected without changing the URL bar.

Comment: does that mean that `www.something.com/?a=admin` becomes `www.something.com/admin` ?  the exact oposite ? or both ?

Comment: It means the exact opposite. www.something.com/admin will silently translate to www.something.com/?a=admin and your PHP file can read the GET['a']=="admin" without it showing up to the user. Then you make all the links in your files call /admin instead of explicitly putting ?a=admin. In more complicated cases, we often set up regular expressions that parse these out automatically with lots of different "pages" -- this is how for example news articles are automatically named on blogs. There is really only one page serving those articles, and htaccess redirects the visible name to a GET.

Comment: do you by any chance know how wordpress redirects to pages when you login as admin , and yet there are no .htaccess files in wordpress directories ?

Comment: but more importantly,  how can i make `www.something.com/?a=admin` to become `www.something.com/admin` in the browser ? is it possible with .htaccess ?

Comment: You're kind of missing the point. You never want to have a link to www.something.com/?a=admin. You ONLY have links to www.something.com/admin, then you use .htaccess to silently redirect it to the ?a=admin page. If you do it the way I wrote here, it will stay "/admin" in the browser URL bar even though it's redirecting.

Comment: will  `www.something.com/?a=admin&b?=test` translate to www.something.com/admin/test  and `www.something.com/?b=test&a?=admin` to www.something.com/test/admin ? how will that work ? shouldnt they give same result ?