# make folder accessible for logged in user

Tags: php, .htaccess

i've seen this post [PHP: make a folder's files accessible, only after a successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091016/php-make-a-folders-files-accessible-only-after-a-successful-login) but still it dosen't work for me.
i have myfolder folder in mysite.com. i want to make mysite.com/myfolder can't be accessed if user don't login. i've tried the .htaccess file in the link above and place it in mysite folder but still mysite.com/myfolder accessible for non logged user. i use 0777 for file permission. can someone tell me what's wrong here?

.htaccess content is

```
<Files ~ "\.(htaccess|include)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.php$">
    php_value auto_prepend_file "startsession.php"
</Files>
```